# How to say "What day/time is convenient for you" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

A potential customer is asking me to come show a demo, and I want to ask what day/time is convenient for them.

What is the usual way to express this?

My attempt:

> Welches Tag/Zeit ist gut für euch?

Google's attempt:

> An welchem ​​Tag und Zeit ist für Sie bequem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most native speakers would say:
"Wann/ Wo passt es Ihnen?"

Comment: I think you should add a note that "Wo" is not referring to the location but to the time, too.

Comment: Sorry, but "Wo" is not reffering to time. "Wo" is reffering to place. The OP edited the question, after my answer. Before the question also reffered to place.

Comment: OK, don't know about that. Nonetheless, "Wo passt es Ihnen" usually refer to time if the context does not point out that they're talking about location.

Comment: Not in my part of Germany. Didn't know that. :)

Comment: OK, then it's a regional thing. So we both learned today :)

Comment: Ähm, kurze google suche zeigt, dass sich "wo passt es dir" in aller regel auf den ort bezieht, nicht selten aber auch zeit und ort zusammenfügt. "Wo passt es dir? Um 12 am Bahnhof." - Nichtsdestotrotz, wenn ich mich mit einem Kollegen mich für ein Meeting verabrede, ist die Frage "Wo passt es dir" nicht selten, wobei das offensichtlich nicht die Frage nach dem Raum ist. Es ist mehr eine Frage der Art "Wo ist in deinem Terminkalender noch Platz", und ich denke dass das oder ähnlich auch die Herkunft der Verwendung von "wo" ist.

Comment: Man lernt überhaupt gar nichts, solange die Leute nicht dazusagen, was mit "hier" gemeint ist. Hier in Berlin, und da wo ich herkomme (Moselfranken) kann man nicht "wo" sagen, um nach einer Zeit zu fragen. Lange Zeit wohnte ich in München, wo man auch nicht "wo" sagte, wenn man "wann" meinte. Auch meine ich dass, solange nicht ausdrücklich gewünscht, Antworten auf Hochdeutsch gegeben werden sollten, nicht in regionalen Dialekten und Slang.

Answer (score 8):

> Wann hätten Sie Zeit?

This would be a polite way to ask. Thereby "Zeit" (eng. time) doesn't necessarily stand for "time". It just asks for any convenient time of event.

Answer (score 6):

I would say :

1. "Wann wollen wir uns zusammensetzen?"
2. "Wann würde es euch terminlich am besten passen?"

(zusammensetzen = sich zueinander finden; zusammen setzen = sich gemeinsam (gleichzeitig) hinsetzen)

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative:

- Wann ist es Ihnen recht?

To take the idea of *convenient* I'd go with

- Wann ist es Ihnen gelegen?

Though that sounds a bit elevated.